# HERE iOS SDK: fine-tuning cluster creation

Tags: ios, swift, here-api

I would like to know how to fine-tune cluster creation using the ios sdk, specifically the radius within which markers have to be for forming a cluster.
Can't find anything in the docu.

For JavaScript there is the H.clustering.Provider to provide clustering options. (https://developer.here.com/documentation/maps/topics/clustering.html)

Anyone know how to do this?

Answer (score 1):

Have you checked the details here: https://developer.here.com/documentation/ios-premium/dev_guide/topics/marker-clustering.html

For example:
Create a new theme and add those styles to the theme with defining the density ranges they should be used for:

```
NMAClusterTheme *theme = [[NMAClusterTheme alloc] init];
[theme setStyle:redStyle forDensityRange:NSMakeRange(10, 9)];
[theme setStyle:greenStyle forDensityRange:NSMakeRange(20, 10)];
```

Comment: Yes, I'm already using this but it's not what I'm looking for. Maybe my question was not clear. This will only set the visuals (ie. color, etc) of a cluster view depending on how many markers are in the cluster. What I'm looking for is settings to determine when markers get added to a cluster in the first place. How close do the need to be together to form a cluster.

Comment: So in the docu for JavaScript I linked there is following passage: "The following example shows a cluster provider initialized with the parameters eps and minWeight. eps holds the value of the radius within which data points are considered for clustering..." I'm looking for something like the eps value for iOS, to set how 'aggressively' clusters are formed on my map.